# Android bluetooth printer got paired but doesn't print

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

Sorry about my english if it's not good.I'm trying to print via bluetooth from my android phone. It detects the device and also pairs. But when i am trying to share the file, the device is not visible in bluetooth device list. While using some application like Bluelib, starprint, printhand,etc bluetooth printer is not able to view them. In short printer is able to pair but not able to print .Why is this happening?

Thanking you
Binesh Nambiar C

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a question related to programming.
If its not something related to programming-coding, please post your answer in [Android Enthusists](https://android.stackexchange.com/)